# How to Prevent Rscript Hangup on Call to system2() on Linux?

Tags: r, linux, parallel-processing, ubuntu-16.04, rscript

I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04 and running R 3.3.1, I have written the following simple Rscript files to demonstrate the problem I'm having:

testR.R:

```
name<- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)[1]

for(i in 1:20000000){
  if(i %% 1000000 == 0){
    print(paste("hello",name,i))
  }
}
print(paste("goodbye", name))
```

testCallTo.R:

```
system2("Rscript", "testR.R david", wait=FALSE)
system2("Rscript", "testR.R john", wait=FALSE)
system2("Rscript", "testR.R sally", wait=FALSE)
system2("Rscript", "testR.R james", wait=FALSE)
```

I run this from the terminal with `Rscript testCallTo.R` and the end of the output looks like this:

```
[1] "hello james 20000000"
[1] "goodbye james"
[1] "hello sally 20000000"
[1] "goodbye sally"
[1] "hello david 20000000"
[1] "goodbye david"
[1] "hello john 20000000"
[1] "goodbye john"
```

Where it never seems to fully terminate and the prompt doesn't re-appear until I use Ctrl-C. This wouldn't be so much of a problem, except that it looks like while it is hung up, it periodically creates empty files in the /tmp directory and doesn't stop until Ctrl-C is used. This is a problem because I want to run scripts with a similar structure over a long time, and if I leave it running unattended it bloats /tmp and then it takes hours to re-boot.

Stranger still is that the files that get generated appear to be locked from the folder GUI, preventing me from deleting them, and invisible to the terminal even with `ls -A` as shown in the screen shot below. If I try to delete it from the terminal with `rm` and the file name, it throws the "file does not exist" error.

The point of this structure is to run several Rscripts in parallel with different parameters passed to them as determined by another Rscript. My instinct tells me that the way I'm attempting to do this is what is leading to this problem, and there must be a better way.

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, works fine for me. (However, tested on ubuntu-14.04.5, so *"grain of salt"*.)

Comment: I don't suppose it would make a difference that I wrote the scripts in RStudio, but ran it from the terminal? I can't imagine why that would matter, but besides that and the ubuntu-version I have no idea why someone else wouldn't see this problem, I've gotten it on two different machines in the same set-up

Comment: The files are just simple text files, so the use of the rstudio editor should make no difference. Do you have anything relevant in your `~/.Rprofile` file that is changing R's behavior?